# Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: Platform mssql does not support offset values in limit queries

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

The error is pretty straight forward. I use Symfony 4 and MSSQL Server as a database server with below configuration:

```
driver: 'sqlsrv'
url: 'mssql://username:password@host:1433/db'
```

The error happens when I use setFirstResult()

```
$entityManager->createQueryBuilder()->select('u')->from(UserEntity::class, 'u')
        ->setFirstResult(20)->setMaxResults(20)
        ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Error message:

```
In AbstractPlatform.php line 3359:
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                    
Platform mssql does not support offset values in limit queries.
```

Trace:

```
 () at /var/www/html/ple-studio/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/AbstractPlatform.php:3359
 Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform->modifyLimitQuery() at /var/www/html/ple-studio/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php:545
 Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker->walkSelectStatement() at /var/www/html/ple-studio/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Exec/SingleSelectExecutor.php:42
 Doctrine\ORM\Query\Exec\SingleSelectExecutor->__construct() at /var/www/html/ple-studio/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php:278
 Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker->getExecutor() at /var/www/html/ple-studio/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php:398
 Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->parse() at /var/www/html/ple-studio/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php:283
 Doctrine\ORM\Query->_parse() at /var/www/html/ple-studio/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php:295
 Doctrine\ORM\Query->_doExecute() at /var/www/html/ple-studio/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php:967
```

The solution that works for me is to manually use raw query:

```
$sql .= ' OFFSET ' . $offset . ' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' . $itemPerPage . ' ROWS ONLY';
```

But this solution will kill the purpose of using ORM and it will not work if I switch to MySQL.

What is the proper way to solve the error above?

Comment: Can't believe Doctrine doesn't map setFirstResult and setMaxResults internally to the "OFFSET / FETCH"-solution. I'm using an external library for a datatable with pagination and can't use the raw query-workaround. I'm trying to get help from the official Doctrine-forums, otherwise I'll start a bounty on this.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you may need to change your config driver value as follows:

```
driver: 'mssql'
```

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url

Comment: This sounds strange, as https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#driver lists `sqlsrv` as the proper driver for MS SQL Server. `mssql` is not listed under the accepted `driver` values